# Docker-proxy prevents container to start after reboot

Tags: linux, networking, proxy, docker, docker-compose

I have a PC used as a NAS running a NextCloud instance as a set of docker containers managed via docker-compose, I'll provide the docker-compose.yml below. My problem is that, even though all my containers are configured as "restart: always", If I reboot the NAS there's only one container that tries to come up, and actually remains in the status "Restarting" indefinitely. As an example, I just rebooted my NAS after some updates and here's the output of `$ docker ps`:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                    COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                          PORTS               NAMES
5679fcfe9174        jrcs/letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion   "/bin/bash /app/entr…"   5 weeks ago         Restarting (1) 18 seconds ago                       nextcloud-letsencrypt
```

If I try to bring up all the container using `$ docker-compose up -d` I get the following output:

```
Starting nextcloud-mariadb ... error
Starting nextcloud-proxy   ... 

ERROR: for nextcloud-mariadb  Cannot start service db: container is marked for removal and cannot be started
Starting nextcloud-proxy   ... error

ERROR: for nextcloud-proxy  Cannot start service proxy: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint nextcloud-proxy (a73acdc99f7fb693a231ffd3b9cbb6d69a96176d41511c259c82a00dfab704a5): Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:443: bind: address already in use

ERROR: for db  Cannot start service db: container is marked for removal and cannot be started

ERROR: for proxy  Cannot start service proxy: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint nextcloud-proxy (a73acdc99f7fb693a231ffd3b9cbb6d69a96176d41511c259c82a00dfab704a5): Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:443: bind: address already in use
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

And in fact, if I look for open ports using `$ sudo netstat -tulpn | grep LISTEN` I get something like:

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1341/systemd-resolv 
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1457/sshd: /usr/sbi 
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      2500/docker-proxy   
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      1457/sshd: /usr/sbi 
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN      2476/docker-proxy
```

After killing the two "docker-proxy" processes and restarting the Docker daemon via `$ sudo systemctl restart docker` I finally get all the containers up and running (including another container that is configured as "restart: always" but isn't part of the NextCloud instance).
**My question is: how can I get Docker to automatically start all my containers after a reboot** without having to manually kill the two "docker-proxy" instances and restart the docker daemon?
The OS I'm using is Ubuntu Server 20.04.1 LTS and my Docker version is 19.03.13, build 4484c46d9d.
Here's the docker-compose.yml for my NextCloud instance:

```
version: '3'  

services:

  proxy:
    image: jwilder/nginx-proxy:alpine
    labels:
      - "com.github.jrcs.letsencrypt_nginx_proxy_companion.nginx_proxy=true"
    container_name: nextcloud-proxy
    networks:
      - nextcloud_network
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    volumes:
      - ./proxy/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d:rw
      - ./proxy/vhost.d:/etc/nginx/vhost.d:rw
      - ./proxy/html:/usr/share/nginx/html:rw
      - ./proxy/certs:/etc/nginx/certs:ro
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro
    restart: always

  letsencrypt:
    image: jrcs/letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion
    container_name: nextcloud-letsencrypt
    depends_on:
      - proxy
    networks:
      - nextcloud_network
    volumes:
      - ./proxy/certs:/etc/nginx/certs:rw
      - ./proxy/vhost.d:/etc/nginx/vhost.d:rw
      - ./proxy/html:/usr/share/nginx/html:rw
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
    restart: always

  db:
    image: mariadb
    container_name: nextcloud-mariadb
    networks:
      - nextcloud_network
    volumes:
      - db:/var/lib/mysql
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=[redacted]
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=[redacted]
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=[redacted]
      - MYSQL_USER=[redacted]
    restart: always

  app:
    image: nextcloud:latest
    container_name: nextcloud-app
    networks:
      - nextcloud_network
    depends_on:
      - letsencrypt
      - proxy
      - db
    volumes:
      - nextcloud-data:/var/www/html
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
    environment:
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=[redacted], [redacted]
      - LETSENCRYPT_HOST=[redacted], [redacted]
      - LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL=[redacted]
    restart: always

volumes:
  nextcloud-data:
    external: true
  db:

networks:
  nextcloud_network:
```